# Macro that selects a product from a slicer so pivot charts changes to reflect selection

Tags: excel, vba

Any help on this much appreciated. I'm trying to set up a list of product buttons and attach a macro to each one that select the product from the slicer and applies the appropriate axes values but the code below won't work.

I created a pivot chart with primary and secondary axes. I have a slicer beside chart that is a list of products. Because the primary axis may be negative in some cases I need to apply different minimum and maximum values for each axis for each product. I tried recording a macro that would run that would A. select the product from the slicer and B. set the appropriate primary and secondary axes min and max settings but when I try to run the macro it won't work correctly, in other words it won't just select 2D Design exclusively and apply axes settings.

Without a macro if I pick another product the axes stay the same as the last product which distorts the display with numbers, especially when negative on primary axis.

```vb
Sub TwoD()

'

' TwoD Macro

'

With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Module112")

.SlicerItems("2D Design").Selected = True

End With

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate

ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).Select

ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = -500

ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = 900

ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select

ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -0.6

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Sub Slicer_Filtering(ByVal ItemToFilter As String, ByVal SecondaryAxisMin As Long, _
                        ByVal SecondaryAxisMax As Long, ByVal PrimaryAxisMin As Long, _
                            Optional ByVal PrimaryAxisMax As Long)
    
    Dim SlicerName As String
    Dim sl As SlicerItem
    Dim ChartName As String
    
    ChartName = "Chart 3" 'Update as needed
    SlicerName = "Slicer_Module112" 'Update as needed
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName).ClearAllFilters
    
    'Filter Only Needed Value
    For Each sl In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName).SlicerItems
        If sl.Name = ItemToFilter Then
            sl.Selected = True
        Else
            sl.Selected = False
        End If
    Next
    
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(ChartName).Activate
    
    'Reset Axes
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
    
    'Set Axes values
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = SecondaryAxisMin
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = SecondaryAxisMax
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = PrimaryAxisMin
    If PrimaryAxisMax <> 0 Then ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = PrimaryAxisMax

    
End Sub
```

And then assign a call to each button with the different values needed for each product. Like this:

```
Sub Caller()

    Call Slicer_Filtering("2D Design", -500, 900, -0.6)

End Sub
```